# How Can I get a Control inside DataGrid RowDetailTemplate

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have this Xaml Code and I want to get the DataGrid "dgRemplacement", I try using Name but it doesn't work also with Uid.

```
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Background="#FF4088C0" Name="DetailGrid">
             <TabControl>                           
                 <TabItem Header="Detaille">                                
                 </TabItem>
                        <TabItem Header="Intervention">                                
                        </TabItem>
                        <TabItem Header="Detaille Intervention">                                
                 </TabItem>
                        <TabItem Header="Remplacement">
                            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                                <DataGrid Name="dgRemplacement" x:Uid="DataGrid1">
                                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Article(Serie)" Binding="{Binding Designation}"/>
                                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Qte" Binding="{Binding Qte}"/>
                                    </DataGrid.Columns>                                        
                                </DataGrid>
                            </Grid>
                        </TabItem>                          
            </TabControl>
            </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

```
private void dgBILigne_RowDetailsVisibilityChanged(object sender, DataGridRowDetailsEventArgs e)
{
        TabControl tc = (e.DetailsElement as Grid).Children[0] as TabControl;
        TabItem ti = tc.Items[3] as TabItem;
}
```

I have succeeded to get the TabItem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
var dataGrid = (e.DetailsElement as FrameworkElement).FindName("dgRemplacement") as DataGrid;
```

[`FindName` Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname.aspx)